# Draw line from center of a circle, Google Maps API, Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geometry, google-polyline

I want to add a line from the center to the border of a circle.

I have already drawn the circle with:

```
circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
   .center(point)
   .radius(radius)
   .strokeWidth(5.5f)
   .strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

Now I want to draw the line...

```
polyLine = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(centerPoint, borderPoint)
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get the border point of the circle.

**How could I draw the line from center to border of the circle and how could it spin in the circle like a radar ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Achieved it by using `GroundOverlay`

```
groundOverlay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
     .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.radar_line))
     .position(point, radius*2)
     .transparency(0.7f)
     .bearing(radarRadius));
```